# HTML5 Canvas + Local Font

Tags: html, canvas, fonts, truetype

I'm trying to make a font viewer in HTML5 where the user selects a true type font on their PC and my code will load it and then render text on the canvas.

I have the file selection working, it returns `c:\fakepath\myfont.ttf`

I have rendering text to the canvas working.

But I'm stumped trying to actually load the selected font as the canvas font. So I'm looking for a way to load a font from a file and set it as the the canvas font, any ideas?

I notice css @font-face can specify custom fonts but can this be changed at run-time once the game has been loaded?

TIA

Comment: How would this ever work in a public site? What if they're not using a PC?

Comment: Its all client side, why shouldn't it work on a public site? Also its a site for computers (mac&pc) not mobile.

Comment: My page all works I just can't figure out how to change font on the fly when a user specfies a custom .ttf font file.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `context.font` property (http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/2dcontext/html5_canvas/#dom-context-2d-font)

You'll have to use the name you declared in the @font-face declaration.

Exemple:

`context.font = 'italic 400 12px/2 Unknown Font, sans-serif';`

You need to set the font before using `fillText`. You'll not be able to "replace" the font of what was already written on your Canvas, since it's not considered anymore as text but as a bitmap data.

Edit:
Ok, you talk about too much things in your question, that confused me.

You just need to upload (if you want to do it async, you can try the HTML5 API).
Then the server need to return you the @font-face declaration that you'll insert in a style element (you can create it dynamically).

Then you just have to use the font as I told you. This is pretty simple:

- Upload the font
- Insert the good @font-face
- Use the font

Comment: So my question is: how can i change the @font-face in javascript when the user has selected a .ttf font file in the file dialog I provide them.

Answer (score 0):

You actually need a client side Javascript way to manipulate your font file to a canvas on the fly.

Take a look at Cufon Fonts:

https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/about

Comment: I've had a quick look and looks more involved, from what I understand its a javascript renderer that loads fonts.

Comment: yes, you don't need to reinvent the wheel actually. you could use just the cufon fonts